# Sensing when a network is available

Tags: c#, memory-management, event-handling

The code below just senses when the network is available and enables/disables a button on the UI. If I am registered to the `NetworkAvailability` event for the life of the program, will it cause a memory leak? I heard it might but didn't understand why.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);


delegate void EnableCallback();

void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
{
    EnableSync();
    //throw new NotImplementedException();            
}

private void EnableSync()
{
    if (this.btnSync.InvokeRequired)
    {
        EnableCallback methodCallback = new EnableCallback(EnableSync);
        this.Invoke(methodCallback, new object[] { });
    }
    else
    {
        if (btnSync.Enabled == true)
            btnSync.Enabled = false;
        else
            btnSync.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if it's for the life of the program as you say, then no. When the program ends, all memory will be released.

Second, this all looks like one class. So root references will be removed when the class is GC'd and no memory leak will occur.

Lastly, write

```
        if (btnSync.Enabled == true)
            btnSync.Enabled = false;
        else
            btnSync.Enabled = true;
```

as

```
        btnSync.Enabled = !btnSync.Enabled;
```

Much more concise.

Comment: Can you use that code  shortcut for any property?

Comment: Any *Boolean*, that is :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Jesse C. Slicer wrote:

Your code will not cause a memory leak. However, it is best to unsubscribe from events when it do not need. I had a few unpleasant occasions when I forgot to unsubscribe from the event and and it was a bad for the app.

In theory, an registered event can cause memory leaks, for example if you use the following code:

```
static class LongLifeClass
{
    public delegate void MyAction();
    public static event MyAction Event;
}


class BigPage
{
    public BigPage()
    {          
        LongLifeClass.Event += new LongLifeClass.MyAction(Notify);
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
    }
}


BigPage bigPage = new BigPage();
BigPage bigPage2 = new BigPage();
```

LongLifeClass.Event will prevent the removal of objects `bigPage, bigPage2`  at the time of garbage collection (if the event is not collected). Because these objects are the **target** of the action.

Comment: Thanks for sharing an example in which it would produce a memory leak to compare with.